# Arranging circuitry paths

Tags: algorithm

Are there any recommended algorithms for placing circuitry?

Restrictions:
Only perfectly vertical/horizontal lines
Can cross at right-angles, but can't run over one another in parallel.

Input:
A set of input points with output points defined. These points have a radius in which no other circuit wire can pass, except for the one going to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit left field, but check out the open source [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) tool. It uses some kind of spring like algorithm from memory to place nodes without overlapping connections. Not sure how suitable it would be for circuitry though: http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery/twopi/twopi2.html